# Showing other attribute value by DTD IDREF

Tags: css, xml, dtd

I got problem with my XML file with DTD. I was make definitions:

```
  <definitions>
    <availableGrades>
      <gradeDefinition name="Role-Playing Game" id="RPG" />
      <gradeDefinition name="First Person Shooter" id="FPS" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Real Time Strategy" id="RTS" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Racing" id="RAC" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Sport" id="SPO" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Third Person Perspective" id="TPP" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Logic" id="LOG" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Arcade" id="ARC" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Strategy" id="STR" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Platform" id="PLA" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Adventure" id="ADV" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Fighting" id="FIG" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Simulator" id="SIM" />
      <gradeDefinition name="Other" id="OTH" />
    </availableGrades>
```

And using:

```
<game grade="FPS" />
```

In DTD I added IDREF:

```
  <!ELEMENT gradeDefinition EMPTY>
  <!ATTLIST gradeDefinition
            name NMTOKENS #REQUIRED
            id ID #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST game grade IDREF #REQUIRED>
```

I'm showing value of grade attribute by CSS (content: attr(grade)) but in browser I see for example FPS. It's possible to print "First Person Shooter" instead "FPS" (by reference to gradeDefinition name)?